# Spring boot migration from 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello I'm trying to upgrade my spring boot version but getting following error,
I have tried enabling circulating reference from configuration but had no success the error is
escription:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.registerBeanDefinitions(DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.java:76)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(java.lang.Class, java.util.function.Supplier)'

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.5/spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.class
    jar:file:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.13/spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder: file:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.5/spring-beans-5.3.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my whole "m2" folder and built it from scratch, it seems maven looks at all possible versions from the repository and circulates through it. (In production mode I use Virtualization so there should be no problem)